# Getting null pointer derefence in Swig-generated Go code

Tags: c, pointers, go, swig

Assuming TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 are `typedefs` to `structs`, I have a function in C like this:

```
int dostuff(TYPE1 *arg1, TYPE2 *arg2, TYPE3 *arg3);
```

The function checks for null pointers and handles them correctly.

I have wrapped this in Go using Swig, resulting in the following:

```
func Dostuff(arg1 TYPE1, arg2 TYPE2, arg3 TYPE3) {
    _swig_i_0 := arg1.Swigcptr()
    _swig_i_1 := arg2.Swigcptr()
    _swig_i_2 := arg3.Swigcptr()
    ...
}
```

If I pass in nil for any of the arguments, I get:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

And the stack trace clearly points to the `argx.Swigcptr()` line as the offender.  I am confused, because from the Swig docs, it supposedly allows null pointers as arguments and simply passes them through as such, leaving checking up to the underlying library code (which is what I want).  Am I doing something obviously incorrect?

I am using Swig 3.0.6 and go 1.4.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need to actually check for null -  before calling the Swigcpter() function?

Comment: So based on this post: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/mq1bMtIOsLM) I tried this:
`Dostuff(x, y, SwigcptrTYPE3(0))`
and it worked.  It seems kludgy to have to do that, I would have expected that the `.Swigcptr()` would have checked for nil and handled it appropriately.

But at least I can move forward now.  I would love to hear, though, if there is some cleaner trick that I'm missing.

Comment: @Neil - I would not have expected to, since this is completely generated code (by Swig).  And since I have a lot of these functions, I would really hate to have to hack that into the generated wrapper after running swig.

Comment: Try it - I can only feel your pain Sandy, however it's sort of pointing to the fact that it might not like the null (nil) passed in.